# Finding natural domain of real functions involving square root and absolute value

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to find the natural domain of the following 2 functions:

1. $ \sqrt{\frac{x+1}{x-2}+3} $
2. $ \sqrt{|x-5| - |x+1|} $

For question 1 I got $[-4,\infty) \cap (-\infty,1]$, but I'm not sure that it is correct. However, I cannot get a solution for the second question.

**Steps for question 1:**

$\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{x-2}+3} $.

The formula will be well defined if:

$\frac{x+1}{x-2}+3 \ge 0 $

$\frac{x+1}{x-2} \ge -3 $

Hence,

$(x+1 \ge -3)\land(x-2>-3)$ or $(x+1\le-3)\land(x-2<-3)$

Their intersection means the domain is $[-4,\infty) \cap (-\infty,1]$ but I assume that that is wrong.

Comment: You might like to include your steps, also how long is the square root for the second problem? You might like to use curly braces to indicate the scope in mathjax.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh Updated, apologies.

Comment: Does the first square root cover the whole thing? or just the first term?

Comment: The whole thing.

Answer (score 2):

For the first question, note that $x \ne 2$,

$$\frac{x+1}{x-2} \ge -3 $$

multiply both sides by $(x-2)^2$,

$$(x+1)(x-2) \ge -3 (x-2)^2$$

$$(x-2)((x+1)+3(x-2)) \ge 0$$

$$(x-2)(4x-5) \ge 0$$

Try to complete it?

For the second question,

We need $$|x-5|-|x+1| \ge 0$$

$$|x-5| \ge |x+1|$$

squaring booth sides

$$x^2-10x+25 \ge x^2+2x +1$$

Can you continue from here?

Comment: Where is the square root in your first line?

Comment: I asked in the comment "Does the first square root cover the whole thing? or just the first term?" and the reply was "the whole thing"

Comment: yes, i think it must cover the whole term, i have saw it even for two minutes

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, you need $\frac{x+1}{x-2} \ge 0$ and $x \neq 2$. You need same sign on numerator and denominator, this is possible only in the interval $x \in (-\infty, -1] \cup (2, \infty)$

For the second part, you can say that distance of $x$ from $5$ must be greater or equal to distance from $-1$, or that $x \in (-\infty, 2]$ because $x=2$ is the midpoint of $-1$ and $5$. Other way is that you simplify the expression in different intervals.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question: we get $$\frac{x+1}{x-2}+3=\frac{4x-5}{x-2}$$
This gives: $$x\geq \frac{5}{4}$$ or $$-\infty<x<2$$
and let $$y=\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{x-2}+3}$$ then the domain is given by $$0<y<2$$ or $$y>2$$
For your second question:
We have $$|x-5|\geq |x+1|$$ after squaring we get $$-\infty<x\le 2$$
and the range is given by $$0\le y\le \sqrt{6}$$

Comment: My apologies, I didn't extend the square root sign far enough, it has since been updated. Thank you!